# is it important to use the same directories for views and models

Tags: laravel

is it important to use the same directories for views controllers and models or you can be free to create files inside created folders and refer to them when needed 
in Laravel MVC

Comment: Views, controllers and models don't use the same directory, they are in separate folders. From the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#introduction): "_... you are free to organize your application however you like. Laravel imposes almost no restrictions on where any given class is located - as long as Composer can autoload the class._"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check docs [Directory Structure](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure)

The default Laravel application structure is intended to provide a great starting point for both large and small applications. But you are free to organize your application however you like. Laravel imposes almost no restrictions on where any given class is located - as long as Composer can autoload the class.

I myself haven't tried doing my own folder structure. I would personally stick with the standard created by Laravel and follow that.